# Getter Method not working after doInBackground

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, android-asynctask

Im trying to have a few getter methods for a few strings to get returned after getting them from an online JSON. In order to save space I decided to put that all in an object and call them from there.

Object:

```
public class InventoryItem extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        String imageURL = "";
        String itemName = "";
        String itemDesc = "";
        String itemRarity = "";
        String itemType = "";
        JSONObject itemJson = null;

        InventoryItem(JSONObject json){
            itemJson = json;
            Log.d("StringSubclass","Inventory Item");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            Log.d("StringSubclass","doInBG Inventory Item");
            try {
                imageURL = "http://www.bungie.net"+itemJson.getJSONObject("Response").getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("inventoryItem").getString("icon");
                Log.d("StringSubclass",imageURL);
                itemName = itemJson.getJSONObject("Response").getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("inventoryItem").getString("itemName");
                itemDesc = itemJson.getJSONObject("Response").getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("inventoryItem").getString("itemDescription");
                itemRarity = itemJson.getJSONObject("Response").getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("inventoryItem").getString("tierTypeName");
                itemType = itemJson.getJSONObject("Response").getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("inventoryItem").getString("itemTypeName");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }


        public String getItemType() {
            return itemType;
        }

        public String getItemRarity() {
            return itemRarity;
        }

        public String getItemDesc() {
            return itemDesc;
        }

        public String getItemName() {
            return itemName;
        }

        public String getImageURL() {
            return imageURL;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the getter methods at the end send back "" even though I changed their value in doInBackground.

This is how I called getImageURL():

```
InventoryItem subclass = new InventoryItem(makeJSON(HOST+"Manifest/6/"+subclassHash+"/"));
            subclass.execute();
            Log.d("StringSubclass",subclass.getImageURL());
            intentHome.putExtra("SubclassImageURL",subclass.getImageURL());
```

makeJSON():

```
 public JSONObject makeJSON(String url){
        JSONObject json = null;
        String apiKey = "36c346318fa54fc6bc659ad6321a6d41";
        try {
            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("X-API-KEY", apiKey);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            String response = "";

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response += inputLine;
            }

            in.close();

            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            JsonObject gson = (JsonObject) parser.parse(response);
            json = new JSONObject(gson.toString());


        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return json;
    }
```

I checked the URL and it is working fine in chrome.

Any help will be appreciated.
I kind of new to this so please explain as much as possible.
Thanks

Comment: (1) Any stack trace in the console?  (2) How do you know whether doInBackground has finished (or even started) when you call the getters?

Comment: You're doing network stuff in `makeJSON` and calling `makeJSON` when you construct your `InventoryItem`. You should probably be calling `makeJSON` from inside `InventoryItem#doInBackground`.

Comment: the way you construct your imageUrl is weird. can you please give us the actual URL?